# Unable to deploy flask-python app on host - IP address

Tags: python-2.7, flask, socket.io, firewall

I have flask/python app that I am running from my virtual desktop using flask run command. It used to run fine with below command.

```
flask run -h (ip address) -p 8000
```

But recently I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I am able to connect to localhost - 127.0.0.1. But, I am getting above error when I connect to IP address.
I want everyone to be able to open this app on their own system. For this, app should be hosted on IP address. On localhost(127.0.0.1), only my system can open it.
I am running this on company laptop, hence there could also be a firewall involved in this.
Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

*getaddrinfo failed* means the hostname can't be resolved, maybe the `-h (ip address)` is wrong, please add the full command you use to start the application.
Generally in production the **-h** parameter is **0.0.0.0** (to allow all clients to communicate with your server), so your command should be:
`flask run -h '0.0.0.0' -p 8000`